# Serial console root login on arm64 Ubuntu server 16.04

Tags: 16.04, server, login, root, systemd

I have extracted an arm64 ubuntu server 16.04 [image](https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/16.04/release/ubuntu-16.04-server-cloudimg-arm64-root.tar.xz) without internet connection. I can boot it but I can't login on the serial console either with root or ubuntu login. Offline, I have modified the /etc/passwd and /etc/shadow files to get "root::...." but it still refuses me to login:

```
Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS ubuntu ttySAC3
ubuntu login: root
Login incorrect
```

I just want to login! How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strangely, modifying the passwd and shadow files offline was not enough. I was not able to chroot either.

The solution was to start a qemu image after a setup with cloud-localds, logging over ssh, doing passwd inside the virtual machine, then copying the rootfs with a qemu utility.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can clearly get into the file system and modify files, then with the image mounted as a directory, try this as root on the hist:

```
chroot /path/to/image
```

Then When you run `passwd`, it should be changing the password of root *in the image*, not on the host. Use `exit` to leave the `chroot`. By using `passwd`, you may fix any problem that might have existed with manually changing the password.